# Get user details from a dropdown list

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

I have a dropdown list populated with users, I want to get the user id and pass to a function whenever a user is selected from the list

An unhandled exception is occurring instead

the exception

```
E/flutter (28482): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

The below snippet is where how I am fetching the users

```
User? sid;
  List<User> users = [];

  //fetch users
  Future<List<User>>? getUsers() async {
    var result = await client.get(usersUrl);
    return userFromJson(result.body);
  }

  Future<void> fetchandShow() async {
    final users = await getUsers();
    setState(() {
      this.users = users ?? [];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchandShow();
  }
```

below is the dropdownbutton where I am displaying the users

```
DropdownButtonFormField<User>(
                    hint: Text('Select user'),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    value: sid,
                    items: users
                        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item,
                              child: Text(
                                item.username,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    onChanged: (item) => setState(() {
                      sid!.id = item as String?;
                      print(sid!.id);
                    }),
                  ),
```

below is where i want to pass the user id

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await createNote(
                      _bodyController.text, int.parse(sid!.id.toString()));
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('submit'),
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item is of User type, Handle onChanged as below:

```
       onChanged: (item) => setState(() {
                  sid = item;
                 
                }),
```

Comment: It's returning an instance of user, it's printing other attributes of user except the "id" which is returning null

Comment: It's working now... I didn't include the 'id' key in my JSON data... Fixed now.... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here "timeZoneType" is the List of data and once the user select any option from the dropdown,  we will get the index ("accountIndex") of the item.
Once we get the index of the item, we can just get that index item details by

"timeZoneType[index]"

var detailData = timeZoneType[index]

```
Column(
    children: [
    Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 45,
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 1),
    child: DropdownButton(
    hint: Text("Timezone", style: Constants.editTextStyleLight),
    value: _currentSelectedValue.value,
    items: timeZoneType
        .map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: value,
    child: Text(
    value,
    style: Constants.editTextStyle,
    ),
    );
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
    print(value);
    accountIndex = timeZoneType.indexOf(value.toString());
    print(accountIndex);
    
    });
    }),
    ),
    ),
    ),
    ],
    )
```

Comment: The method 'indexOf' isn't defined for the type 'User'